# Ubuntu apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r) does not gives me kernel source

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, source-code

I am trying to download linux kernel source code for ubuntu distribution. I did this directly in my home folder.

```
kerndev@kerndev-VirtualBox:~$ uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic
kerndev@kerndev-VirtualBox:~$ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)  
Reading package lists... 
Done Picking 'linux-signed-hwe' as source package instead of 'linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic'  
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux-signed-hwe_5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1.dsc'  
Skipping already downloaded file 'linux-signed-hwe_5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1.tar.xz'  
Need to get 0 B of source archives. Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in linux-signed-hwe-5.0.0
```

After this step I just see following (excerpt).

```
kerndev@kerndev-VirtualBox:~$ ls -ltr
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 3 kerndev kerndev  4096 Apr  5  2019 linux-signed-hwe-5.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 kerndev kerndev 11356 Nov 15 02:13 linux-signed-hwe_5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 kerndev kerndev  1862 Nov 15 02:13 linux-signed-hwe_5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1.dsc
```

Here again I do not see kernel source though (even in debian directory)

```
kerndev@kerndev-VirtualBox:~/linux-signed-hwe-5.0.0$ ls -ltr
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kerndev kerndev 2683 Apr  5  2019 update-version
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kerndev kerndev  216 Apr  5  2019 generate-depends
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kerndev kerndev  450 Apr  5  2019 download-unsigned
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kerndev kerndev 6491 Apr  5  2019 download-signed
drwxr-xr-x 5 kerndev kerndev 4096 Nov 14 15:59 debian
```

I remember I downloaded headers earlier and struggled to update source.list file. What I may be missing?

Comment: Try `apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)`

Comment: many Thanks it did work - if you write this as answer I will accept it

Comment: I actually gave you not quite the right answer. I was trying what was recommended on [the ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode), and it appeared to work on 18.04. But looking more closely, it will download the source for the kernel most recently released by Canonical for your architecture, not the version you're currently running. I will have to look into this some more to give a proper answer.